# How to make static style-sheet working in django?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

By running this code in normal *html* it runs with style also. But whenever I run it in django it does not run and just show me text.

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html');
```

**main url**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- Animate.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '../static/css/animate.css' %}">
<!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '../static/css/icomoon.css' %}">
<!-- Simple Line Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '../static/css/simple-line-icons.css' %}">

<section id="fh5co-home" data-section="home" style="background-image: url(../static/images/W1.png);" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-wrap">
            <div class="text-inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                     <h1 class="to-animate">Welcome in the World of White Hats</h1>
                        <h2 class="to-animate">Your Problem with auto Solution</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**Folder structure**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

`href="{% static '../static/...`

Try with:

`href="{% static '../css/...`

Also, need to include this: `{% load static %}` at the beginning of all your templates where you want to use static files.

Answer (score 0):

[static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static) template tag adds `STATIC_ROOT` to the given URL. So check [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) value in settings.py and change relative paths from

```
{% static '../static/css/animate.css' %}
```

to

```
{% static 'css/animate.css' %}
```

Note, you need this in the beginning of your template to make `static` work:

```
{% load static %}
```

Comment: Such a response does not really help to help you. Please update your question with modified template code and post actual error message/HTTP status. Also please check final CSS URL in rendered page (inspect element / view source).